# ROS Noetic environment setup (directory not found)

Tags: installation, ros, environment

After I installed Ros Noetic with this command - **sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full**. There are 2-3 errors which are of not being able to fetch a few packages(armadillo and other). I downloaded them later.
But after I typed this command - **source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash**, I got this error of - **no such file or directory**. I then added this command in  .bashrc file and removed it after one execution realizing this file cannot be found by the computer (may be a different location but still can't locate). Then I reinstalled ROS noetic, this time in another folder I made .... and I still cannot locate the file and I am getting the same error again. I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager with UBUNTU_20.04. I also installed Guest editions(for full screen purposes)

Comment: By default ROS is installed into /opt/ros/..  if you are installing it somewhere else then you won't find the file there.  Can you post the actual error messages.

Comment: I am sorry. I forget to reply. I ran the command: sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full    again, even after running it once. The problem got automatically solved. I did not understand why I had to run that command twice, but I did and it worked. Thank you very much for replying btw.